# Drawing a circle with random color in canvas on mouse click

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to develop a simple canvas application using html5 and javascript. I want to make a circle depending on the position of mouse click in the canvas. Each time user clicks in canvas a circle should be drawn. Moreover the color of circle needs to be randomly selected. I have written the random color and position function to get x and y position of mouse in canvas. But when i run nothing is happening.

Here is my html code:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="circle.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">

 #testCanvas {
       border: 2px solid;
 }
</style>  

</head>
<body>

     <canvas id="testCanvas" width="400" height="400"> </canvas>

</body>
```

Here's my javascript code:

```
window.onload = init;

function init() {
// access the canvas element and its context
 var canvas = document.getElementById("testCanvas");
 var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var pos = getMousePos(canvas, e);
posx = pos.x;
posy = pos.y;
context.fillStyle = randomColor();

// fill a circle
context.beginPath();
context.arc(posx,posy, 30, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
context.fill();
context.closePath();

 }

 function randomColor() {
    var color = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
     color.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 256));
    }
    return 'rgb(' + color.join(',') + ')';
   }

function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
   x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
   y: evt.clientY - rect.top
 };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement a click handler for the canvas so that every time you click on it you will receive a notification in form of an event:

```js
// access the canvas element and its context
var canvas = document.getElementById("testCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

// add click handler
canvas.onclick = function(e) {
  var pos = getMousePos(canvas, e);     // get position as before
  context.fillStyle = randomColor();    // get the fill color

  // fill a circle
  context.beginPath();                  // now we can draw the circle at click
  context.arc(pos.x, pos.y, 30, 0, 2 * Math.PI); // use pos object directly like this
  context.fill();
  // closePath() not needed here and won't work after fill() has been called anyways
}

function randomColor() {
  var color = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    color.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 256));
  }
  return 'rgb(' + color.join(',') + ')';
}

function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
    y: evt.clientY - rect.top
  };
}
```

```css
canvas {border: 1px solid #999}
```

```html
<canvas id="testCanvas" width="400" height="400"> </canvas>
```

Comment: do i need to write the event handler in the init()  or draw () method which is called at first?

Comment: @Rahila the handler can be added inside the init() function for example (I cannot see any draw() method but perhaps init is what you meant?)

Comment: yes init method. Because if i run without adding in the init() method it doesnt show anything which means i need to call a particular function of js. Right?

Comment: Could you tell how can i hide the overlapping circles? Like if the user clicks on two spots next to each other the circle before the new one should hide?

Comment: @Rahila that would be far more complicated and out of scope for this question. You would have to track all clicks in for example an array, and redraw, then implement logistics/hit-test for when a circle should be removed and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example / way of adding an event handler. You can change 'click' to 'mousemove' and others to try different things.

```
// access the canvas element and its context
window.onload = init;

function init(){
  var canvas = document.getElementById("testCanvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  function drawCircle(pos,canvas){
    posx = pos.x;
    posy = pos.y;
    context.fillStyle = randomColor();

  // fill a circle
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(posx,posy, 30, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
    context.fill();
    context.closePath();

  }

  function randomColor() {
   var color = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    color.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 256));
   }
   return 'rgb(' + color.join(',') + ')';
  }

  function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
    x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
    y: evt.clientY - rect.top
    } ;
  }

  canvas.addEventListener('click', function(evt){
    var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas,evt);
    drawCircle(mousePos,canvas);
  },false);
}
```